# django 1.6 authentication in Custom User model

Tags: django, django-users

I define a custom User model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   somefield = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

and I add AUTH_USER_MODEL to settengs :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'userm.CustomUser'
```

but when I try this command the authenticate function return None:

```
In [36]: from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

In [37]: CustomUser.objects.create(username='root',password='root')
Out[37]: <CustomUser: root>

In [38]: authenticate(username='root', password='root')
```

and the result of objects.all is:

```
In [47]: CustomUser.objects.all()
Out[47]: [<CustomUser: admin>, <CustomUser: nima>, <CustomUser: ali>, <CustomUser: root>, <CustomUser: esi>, <CustomUser: sha>]
```

am I missed something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is that the password is not saved correctly with the `create` method.

Instead try doing this

```
u=CustomUser.objects.create(username='root1')
u.set_password('root')
u.save()
```

Then 
    `authenticate(username='root1', password='root')` will work (at least it worked in my case).

**Update**: Also, please take a look at the `create_user` of the 
[django ducmentation custom user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example):

```
def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
    # [...]
    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
    )
    # Explicitly set password with the set_password method
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

So you should not use `CustomUser.objects.create` to set the password.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is because you have just created an object not saved in Database so  authenticate dont return any object. If you debug authenticate method you can see this.

So could you try :

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
u = CustomUser.objects.create(username='root',password='root')
u.save()
authenticate(username='root', password='root')
```

Comment: Actually, ``create`` *will* save the object to the database.

Comment: I add objects.all() output to my post so the problem is not in the saving object

Comment: I think you have to look the implementation of authenticate method and find why this method returns None.